# How can I use a struct as key in a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I have the following code, but I get an error on on the last line:

```
struct coord { 
    int x, y; 

    bool operator=(const coord &o) {
        return x == o.x && y == o.y;
    }

    bool operator<(const coord &o) {
        return x < o.x || (x == o.x && y < o.y);
    }
};

map<coord, int> m;
pair<coord, int> p((coord{0,0}),123);
m.insert(p); // ERROR here
```

How can I use a struct as key in a map?

---

I tried to change the code to this:

```
struct coord { 
    int x, y; 

    bool const operator==(const coord &o) {
        return x == o.x && y == o.y;
    }

    bool const operator<(const coord &o) {
        return x < o.x || (x == o.x && y < o.y);
    }
};
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\tomc\Desktop\g>mingw32-make g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/string:5 0:0,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/loc ale_classes.h:42,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/ios
_base.h:43,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/ios:43,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/ostream: 40,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/iostream :40,
                 from test.cpp:1: c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h: In member  function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const
_Tp&) const [with _ Tp = coord]': c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:1184:4: inst antiated from 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key,  _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
_Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key
= coord, _Val = std::pair<const coord, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std:: pair<const coord, int> >, _Compare = std::less<coord>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const coord, int>>]' c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:501:41: insta ntiated from 'std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>,  std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key,
_Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind <std::map<_Key, _Tp,
_Compare, _Alloc>::value_type>::other>::iterator, bool> std ::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::map<_Key, _Tp,
_Compare, _ Alloc>::value_type&) [with _Key = coord, _Tp = int,
_Compare = std::less<coord>,  _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const coord, int> >, typename std::_Rb_tree<_ Key, std::pair<const _Key,
_Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _ Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
_Alloc>::value_ty pe>::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const coord, int> >, st d::map<_Key,
_Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const coord, int>]' test.cpp:56:12:   instantiated from here c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:230:22: er ror: passing 'const coord' as 'this' argument of 'const bool coord::operator<(co nst coord&)' discards qualifiers mingw32-make: *** [game] Error 1
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This isn't your problem but your operator= needs to be operator==

Comment: It should be `bool operator<(const coord &o) const`

Comment: const in the wrong place, after the argument list not before. What you did makes the return type const i.e. `const bool`, but you want to make the method const.

Comment: Read the [Operator Overloading FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). In fact, this should be closed as a dupe, since it's all explained there.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try and make `operator <` `const`:

```
bool operator<(const coord &o)  const {
```

(Your `= operator` should probably be `== operator` and `const` as well)

Comment: Why adding `const` resolves the error , can you explain? , thanks

Comment: Actually, [I'd make the operator a free function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) rather than a member function.

Comment: @x4:  The key of a map is of type "const Key", so you can only perform operations on the struct that are marked as `const`.  Trying to use methods that are not marked as `const` in that case results in the error above (using XXX discards qualifiers)

Answer (score 13):

By far the simplest is to define a global "less than" operator for your struct in stead of as a member function.

std::map uses - by default - the 'lessthan' functor which, in turn, uses the global "operator<" defined for the key type of the map.

```
bool operator<(const coord& l, const coord& r) {
     return (l.x<r.x || (l.x==r.x && l.y<r.y));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392682/2675154) by *Andrii*, you can provide a custom comparison object to the `map` instead of defining `operator<` for your struct. Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison object. Moreover, you don't need to define `operator==` for your struct to make the `map` work. As a result, you can keep your struct as short as this:

```
struct coord {
    int x, y;
};
```

And the rest of your code could be written as follows:

```
auto comp = [](const coord& c1, const coord& c2){
    return c1.x < c2.x || (c1.x == c2.x && c1.y < c2.y);
};
std::map<coord, int, decltype(comp)> m(comp);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/CrMAnY)

Comment: This is super useful for when you don't have access to the struct's code itself and need to add it to a map. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, which may be used for third-party data types, is to pass a `Comparison object` as third template parameter.
[example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/)