# c++ using structs as data for a <map, <map, vector>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, struct

I am having a problem trying to load a map that has another map/vector combination as the value with structs.  Below is my code which I have tried to simplify as much as I could:

```
    //These are the structs
    struct Order 
    {
        std::string A;
        std::string B;
    };

    struct Card
    {
        std::string C;
        std::string D;
    };

    struct Item  
    {
        std::string E;
        std::string F;
    };

    //this is the method that will read and load the map
    void LoadMap(ListofValues object)
    {
    std::map<Order, std::map<Item, std::vector<Card>>> records; //THIS is the data structure I'm trying to store into

    //ListofValues is a list passed that holds all these values that will need to be put into my map
    for(std::vector<ListofValues>::iterator vIter= object.begin(); vIter != object.end(); ++vIter)
            {           
                std::string sReceiptRecord = (*vIter).getReceipt(m_StdOrderConfirmVer);

                Order order = {(*vIter).getA,(*vIter).getB}; 
                Item item = {(*vIter).getC,(*vIter).getD}; 
                Card card = {wws::String((*vIter).getE), (*vIter).getF}; 

                records[order][item].push_back(card); //load into my map            
            }
      }
```

So I will have an object passed that contains a list of all the values (ListofValues).  I will iterate through that list and with the getter methods, I will store those values into the structs (getE returns a Long which is why the conversion was necessary). Is there a step I'm missing

An error I'm getting is:

```
error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Order' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  You have a compiler error, and if I took your code as-is, I would have a ton of them.

Comment: I think you need an operator <() for your class Order.

Comment: Not sure how he's getting the error he claims - he's calling .begin() and .end() on the TYPE of the variable he passed in.  Really need the MCVE

Comment: @OP See [this](http://ideone.com/po2m8O)?  Same error, and the example is complete.  All C++ errors can be recreated with a simple example, and you should have broken your code down to discover what is causing the problem, instead of having vectors, `String`, iterators, etc...

Comment: Sorry all, I confused myself while trying to translate the specific code into a more concise, general code.  There's about a hundred lines I had to take out just to get the parts that are relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an operator < for your struct to be used as a key for the map, see this question: [Struct as a key in a std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204283/struct-as-a-key-in-a-stdmap)

Answer (score 2):

`ListOfValues` is the TYPE of the parameter passed to `LoadMap`, `object` is the actual variable.

In your for loop, you need to say `object.begin()` and `object.end()`.

I'm getting very different compiler errors than what you say you're getting.   Did you post the right code?

Here's what I see: https://godbolt.org/g/xl4zWw